# Write down all combinations of binary string

Tags: r

I have a string of length 5.
Each element of the string can take on two values 0 and 1.

I would like to write down all possible permutations.

For example:

```
0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
.
.
.
1 1 1 1 1
```

There are 2^5 such combinations.

I know there is a command called `combn` but I do not know how to handle the fact that each digit can take on two possible values.

Comment: If you want a fast solution you could also try `data.table` `CJ` function. I.e, `library(data.table); CJ(0:1, 0:1, 0:1, 0:1, 0:1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your all 2^5 = 32 combinations by using :

```
install.packages('gtools')
library(gtools)
permutations(2,5,v=c(0,1),repeats.allowed=TRUE)
```

Comment: this solution is much faster for higher values, for example if the string is of length 50.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps not the best way to do it, but it works:

```
> expand.grid(0:1, 0:1, 0:1, 0:1, 0:1)
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
1     0    0    0    0    0
2     1    0    0    0    0
3     0    1    0    0    0
4     1    1    0    0    0
5     0    0    1    0    0
6     1    0    1    0    0
7     0    1    1    0    0
8     1    1    1    0    0
9     0    0    0    1    0
10    1    0    0    1    0
11    0    1    0    1    0
12    1    1    0    1    0
13    0    0    1    1    0
14    1    0    1    1    0
15    0    1    1    1    0
16    1    1    1    1    0
17    0    0    0    0    1
18    1    0    0    0    1
19    0    1    0    0    1
20    1    1    0    0    1
21    0    0    1    0    1
22    1    0    1    0    1
23    0    1    1    0    1
24    1    1    1    0    1
25    0    0    0    1    1
26    1    0    0    1    1
27    0    1    0    1    1
28    1    1    0    1    1
29    0    0    1    1    1
30    1    0    1    1    1
31    0    1    1    1    1
32    1    1    1    1    1
```

Comment: or `expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),5))`

Comment: Thanks, good point, @akrun

Comment: thank you for this solution. the only problem is that it is very slow if you want to apply it to larger strings, for example 20.

Comment: @user2733997, I was sure hat there is some special function for this (that's why I wrote perhaps not the best way), just wanted to show a simple alternative that came to my mind.